# Read values of object inside array - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Below is my object inside array. I need to display the list reading this array.

```
let res = {      
  details: [
        {
            "code":"123",
            "name":"tye"
        },
        {
            "code":"456",
            "name":"San Joaquin"
        },
        {
            "code":"789",
            "name":"Stanislaus"
        },
    ]
};
```

I need to read and display `details.code` which does not work. I need to display list of all `code`

```
123
456
789
```

I do not need individual to display. Not like `details[0].code`. Below is what i have done

```
let det = [];
Object.keys(res.details).forEach((code) => {            
     det.push(res.details[code])
});
```

Here `det` does not give list of `code`. How to achieve this?

Comment: `res.details.forEach(({ code }) => console.log(code))`

Comment: res.details is an array use for loop `res.details.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
});`

Comment: try ```det.push(res.details[code.code])```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` function. Its more appropriate than having separate array and using `forEach` push items into it.

```js
let res = {      
  details: [
        {
            "code":"123",
            "name":"tye"
        },
        {
            "code":"456",
            "name":"San Joaquin"
        },
        {
            "code":"789",
            "name":"Stanislaus"
        },
    ]
};

const mapped = res.details.map(item => item.code);

console.log(mapped);
```

You can also destruct the object in the parameters list

```
const mapped = res.details.map(({ code }) => code);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `map()` which is more suitable in your case:

```js
let res = {      
  details: [
        {
            "code":"123",
            "name":"tye"
        },
        {
            "code":"456",
            "name":"San Joaquin"
        },
        {
            "code":"789",
            "name":"Stanislaus"
        },
    ]
};


let codeArr  = res.details.map(c => c.code);

console.log(codeArr);
```

If you want to use `forEach()` just ignore `Object.keys`:

```js
let res = {      
  details: [
        {
            "code":"123",
            "name":"tye"
        },
        {
            "code":"456",
            "name":"San Joaquin"
        },
        {
            "code":"789",
            "name":"Stanislaus"
        },
    ]
};

let det = [];
res.details.forEach(code => det.push(code.code));
console.log(det)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
let res = {      
  details: [
        {
            "code":"123",
            "name":"tye"
        },
        {
            "code":"456",
            "name":"San Joaquin"
        },
        {
            "code":"789",
            "name":"Stanislaus"
        },
    ]
};
var data = res.details.map(function(item) { return item["code"]; });

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may not require Object.keys here.Use array `map` method , it will return an array of code value

```js
let res = {
  details: [{
      "code": "123",
      "name": "tye"
    },
    {
      "code": "456",
      "name": "San Joaquin"
    },
    {
      "code": "789",
      "name": "Stanislaus"
    },
  ]
};
let det = res.details.map((code) => {
  return code.code
});
console.log(det)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var details = [
        {
            "code":"123",
            "name":"tye"
        },
        {
            "code":"456",
            "name":"San Joaquin"
        },
        {
            "code":"789",
            "name":"Stanislaus"
        },
    ]

for(var i=0;i< details.length;i++)
{
   var markup='<li>'+ details[i].code+'</li>';
    $('ul').append(markup);
}
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<ul>
</ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let res = {      
  details: [
        {
            "code":"123",
            "name":"tye"
        },
        {
            "code":"456",
            "name":"San Joaquin"
        },
        {
            "code":"789",
            "name":"Stanislaus"
        },
    ]
};

var arr = [];
for (var key in res.details) {
    var obj = res.details[key].code;
    arr.push(obj);
}
    console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why people are suggesting answers with `map`. Conventionally, we use `map` when we are actually modifying the array of object to some other structure. You can use `forEach` to achieve this followed by destructuring assignment inside `forEach` like `{code}` in the `forEach` function that will get you the value of the `code` property of each object in the `res.details` array:

```js
let res = {
  details: [
    {
      "code":"123",
      "name":"tye"
    },
    {
      "code":"456",
      "name":"San Joaquin"
    },
    {
      "code":"789",
      "name":"Stanislaus"
    },
  ]
};
var codeArray = [];
res.details.forEach(({code}) => codeArray.push(code));

console.log(codeArray);
```

Comment: You you are modifying it to some other structure?! You're mapping an object to a string. Your answer is exactly OPPOSITE of what you're supposed to do. `map` is correct.

Comment: @Li357 please comment after investigating the code and output

Comment: I know what the code is supposed to do and what yours does. If you have to forEach and push to another array, then you can `map` which is preferred.